# is it possible to have java fill in the blanks on a word document

Tags: java

I am making a java program where I input answers for a friendship survey. It spits out the student's top ten friends. However I need to print out the results and give them to the students. The old of doing it was to have the java program write to write html then we would open each file one at a time and print out the page. However, having 400+ students to do it for takes a while.

So since I am re making the program I would like to make it so I can just have it on word files and print them all out at once. However, I don't know how to write to a word file and notepad isn't stylish enough. Anyone know how to make this possible or another way that is easier?

Comment: Apache POI gives the ability to read and write, in Java, all sorts of Microsoft office files.

Comment: have you done any work w/ Java 8 & streams & collectors? If you stream the answers & than end up using a Collectors.joining that should do your trick.

Comment: If using Java is just an idea but not a requirement, you might actually be better off using Word's [Mail Merge Functionality](https://www.timeatlas.com/mail-merge-word-excel/) which lets you set up a spreadsheet with all the information to fill, then it prints out all the sheets with your base template (the survey) and the answers for each student (Information from the spreadsheet).

Comment: Programmingto do (several/a) print job(s) on (several) HTMLs seems the least effort. (If not considering MSWord forms)

Comment: Having used Apache POI to write office documents before I have to say, writing to html and just taking a snippet of code to loop through all the files in a directory and print them seems like it would be a lot less effort.

Comment: If the documents don't have to be separate for any reason, you could add CSS 'page-break-before: always' before each section and just have one big html file that prints correctly.

Comment: Yeah, what Mark said. Why rewrite the whole thing in Word? You should be able to produce just a single HTML doc with all the results & good printing.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing some years ago, using Rich Text Format. Its advantage is that it's a plain text format that can easily be manipulated.

I created the form document in Word with some unique placeholder strings where I'd later fill in the actual data and saved it as RTF.

With a text editor, I made sure that Word didn't split the placeholders by inserting some junk formatting directives, and corrected that manually where necessary.

Then, filling in the actual data just meant to do some simple text replacement (in my case, there was no risk to interfere with the formatting directives), and saving the resulting RTF file.

As Word typically opens RTF files just as easy as DOC or DOCX ones, this was an easy working solution for me.